# Error: Can't convert from 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task' to 'System.Action'

Tags: c#

I am taking a file with an .mpp extension so I can read it with Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject

But it shows me the following error

> Can't convert from 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task' to 'System.Action'

```
public new string Load(string fileName)
    {
        MSProject.ApplicationClass app = null;
        string retVal = "";
        ArrayList tasks = new ArrayList();

        try
        {
            // execute the Microsoft Project Application
            app = new MSProject.ApplicationClass();

            // Do not display Microsoft Project
            app.Visible = false;

            // open the project file.
            if (app.FileOpen(fileName, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, MSProject.PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadOnly, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing))
            {
                // go through all the open projects--there should only be one
                foreach (MSProject.Project proj in app.Projects)
                {
                    // go through all the tasks in the project
                    foreach (MSProject.Task task in proj.Tasks)
                    {
                        // add Microsoft Project Task to arraylist                          
                        tasks.Add(new Task(task));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                retVal = "The MS Project file " + fileName + " could not be opened.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retVal = "Could not process the MS Project file " + fileName + "." + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.Message + System.Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace;
        }

        // close the application if is was opened.
        if (app != null)
        {
            app.Quit(MSProject.PjSaveType.pjDoNotSave);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

I am working with WindowsForm and where the error marks me is:

```
foreach (MSProject.Task task in proj.Tasks)
                    {
                        // add Microsoft Project Task to arraylist                          
                        tasks.Add(new Task(task)); <= Error
                    }
```

Can anyone support me with this

Comment: `List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();`

Comment: I had already tried it and the following error appears: A local variable or a parameter called 'tasks' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is being used in a surrounding local scope to define a local variable or a parameter

Comment: `tasks.Add(task);`

Comment: You should add the above line replacing ArrayList. `ArrayList tasks = new ArrayList();` to `List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();`